# React Material Table IE 11 issue

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, material-ui, internet-explorer-11

I am using the React Material table(Editable) in IE11. Once I click on Delete/Edit and then click on the cancel button only the row is highlighted other rows are disabled. But in chrome, all the rows are enabled.[image]

once I click on delete and then click on the cancel button
[image]

all other rows are disabled in IE11 but in chrome, all the rows are highlighted
[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue with the code that you had shared in the picture. I suggest you try to create a sample material table and post it using the code snippet. It can help us to reproduce the issue easily. Thanks for your understanding.